# find primes in a certain range efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, range, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

This is code an algorithm I found for Sieve of Eratosthenes for python3.  What I want to do is edit it so the I can input a range of bottom and top and then input a list of primes up to the bottom one and it will output a list of primes within that range.
However, I am not quite sure how to do that.
If you can help that would be greatly appreciated.

```
from math import sqrt
def sieve(end):  
    if end < 2: return []  

    #The array doesn't need to include even numbers  
    lng = ((end//2)-1+end%2)  

    # Create array and assume all numbers in array are prime  
    sieve = [True]*(lng+1)  

    # In the following code, you're going to see some funky  
    # bit shifting and stuff, this is just transforming i and j  
    # so that they represent the proper elements in the array.  
    # The transforming is not optimal, and the number of  
    # operations involved can be reduced.  

    # Only go up to square root of the end  
    for i in range(int(sqrt(end)) >> 1):  

        # Skip numbers that aren’t marked as prime  
        if not sieve[i]: continue  

        # Unmark all multiples of i, starting at i**2  
        for j in range( (i*(i + 3) << 1) + 3, lng, (i << 1) + 3):  
            sieve[j] = False  

    # Don't forget 2!  
    primes = [2]  

    # Gather all the primes into a list, leaving out the composite numbers  
    primes.extend([(i << 1) + 3 for i in range(lng) if sieve[i]])  

    return primes
```

Comment: this is for euler 216, i can sieve all the primes up to 100 million in 100 seconds on my netbook, but i need them up to 159 million for the primes up to sqrt of 50000000^2*10 which is about 158 and change, so i need that last 59 million in a new list because i get a memory error.

i am an mechanical engineering student at georgia tech and am trying learn the uniqueness of python to avoid matlab as much as possible because it is to finicky for me

Comment: Thanks for the context, the question doesn't look so contrived anymore. The performance hints are pretty relevant. Also good on you for doing the Euler project.

Comment: I believe that *space complexity*, not *time complexity* is the limiting factor for your netbook with this algorithm. The seive requires ***O(n)*** space. You may want to seive for primes in blocks of 100 million to reduce the space you are using at any given time. Also, to reduce space, you may want to use a byte array and bit flags rather then boolean values. The bit masking may be a bit more complicated but it will likely reduce your space usage by a factor of 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following is working:

```
def extend_erathostene(A, B, prime_up_to_A):
    sieve = [ True ]* (B-A)
    for p in prime_up_to_A:
        # first multiple of p greater than A
        m0 = ((A+p-1)/p)*p
        for m in range( m0, B, p):
            sieve[m-A] = False
    limit = int(ceil(sqrt(B)))
    for p in range(A,limit+1):
        if sieve[p-A]:
            for m in range(p*2, B, p):
                sieve[m-A] = False 
    return prime_up_to_A + [ A+c for (c, isprime) in enumerate(sieve) if isprime]
```

Comment: you only need to sieve it by the primes up to sqrt of B, not all the primes up to A. That's a ginormous overkill.

Comment: Not exactly. The code above says: `for p in prime_up_to_A`. But you only need primes up to `sqrt(B)`. That may or may not be much smaller than `A`, and for most reasonable values of `A, B` it will be (the range is usually relatively narrow). If it is, your first loop will work overtime, and the second won't do any work at all. Plus, you only really need to start from `p*p`, not `2*p`, in the second loop, and use `2*p` instead of `p` as a step, in both loops, for all primes except the very first one (`2`).

Answer (score 2):

This problem is known as the "segmented sieve of Eratosthenes."  Google gives several useful references.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the primes from 2 to `end`, so you just need to filter the list that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to run the sieve code with `end = top` and modify the last line to give you only numbers bigger than bottom:

If the range is small compared with it's magnitude (i.e. top-bottom is small compared with bottom), then you better use a different algorithm:

Start from bottom and iterate over the odd numbers checking whether they are prime. You need an isprime(n) function which just checks whether n is divisible by all the odd numbers from 1 to sqrt(n):

```
def isprime(n):
    i=2
    while (i*i<=n):
        if n%i==0: return False
        i+=1
    return True
```